# TYPO3 Backend Image Manipulation: rotate images?

Tags: typo3

I was wondering if there is any possibility for an editor to rotate images with the image manipulation wizard - just like the cropping tool. Am I missing something or is this feature not available yet?

[image: TYPO3 Backend image manipulation wizard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TYPO3 does not support image rotation.

Comment: Too bad - will have to file a feature request then.

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/2936
Too late. The request exists for 10 yrs now ... ;-)

Comment: That request is for TinyMCE, not for the standard TYPO3 image editor.